# A single Validation across whole application Revised

Tags: java, javascript, struts-1

I have an appliaction in which there are multiple text fields in one jsp , and there are two more jsp which contain  text fields .

Now a/c to my application, one jsp(general.jsp) is filled first and then data is saved , then 2nd  jsp(contact.jsp) is filled and the filled data is saved by using the save button at the end of the form . now the third jsp is filled in the same way.....
these jsp are given in the form of a hyperlink in my left navigation , one after another,(in a leftnavigation.jsp) 
Now there is a submit button hyperlink(just below the othr jsp in leftnavigation.jsp ) which gets activated once all the three forms are submitted(saved).

Now my problem is to validate all the text fields (of the three jsps) on clicking this  submit button hyperlink.
say it is general.jsp:-

```
<form name="input" action=" " method="get">
 Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form> 
  say it is contact.jsp:-  

<form name="input" action=" " method="get">
 contact: <input type="text" name="contact" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form> 

   leftnav.jsp:-   

           <%
               if(isSubmitToBeShown){
                    // submitClass="class=\"nav4_body\"";
                    linkStart = "<a href=\"javascript:performAction();\">";
                    linkEnd = "</a>";
                    submitImage = "submit_orange_broad.gif";
                    isSubmitMessage = NO;
                }
                else{
                    linkStart="";
                    linkEnd="";
                    submitImage = "submit_grey_broad.gif";
                    isSubmitMessage = YES;
                }
                %>
```

Comment: @JibiAbraham......code is too big......

Comment: @JibiAbraham....i have edited my problem to make it more clear

Comment: Do you have access to the complete form (all 3 steps) once this submit button is activated? If so, then its a simple matter. Let me know

Comment: @JibiAbraham.....yes i have access

Comment: ok, now please provide me a sample html structure, so that i can help you

Comment: @JibiAbraham...i have added the sample code.......right now i am using struts framework,jsp, js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jsp too much, but from the code you just posted, it seems to me that you can do things in the following way

```
//if submit button is to be shown - true
//and you use jquery on your page
$('form[name="input"]').find('input[type="text"]')
.each(function(i, item){
    //perform your validations here
});
```

Would something like this be what you are looking for?

### Edit 2 - using javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('form input[type=text]')
```

This will give you an array of all your required elements and you can work on it.